# can't find the right compression for this webpage (python requests.get)

Tags: python, python-requests, html-compression

I can load this webpage in Google Chrome, but I can't access it via `requests`. Any idea what the compression problem is?

#### Code:

```
import requests


url = r'https://www.huffpost.com/entry/sean-hannity-gutless-tucker-carlson_n_60d5806ae4b0b6b5a164633a'
headers = {'Accept-Encoding':'gzip, deflate, compress, br, identity'}

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

### Result:

```
ContentDecodingError: ('Received response with content-encoding: gzip, but failed to decode it.', error('Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect header check'))
```

Comment: what makes you think its compressed at all?

Comment: @JoranBeasley perhaps `Received response with content-encoding: gzip`?

Answer (score 1):

Use a user agent that emulates a browser:

```
import requests

url = r'https://www.huffpost.com/entry/sean-hannity-gutless-tucker-carlson_n_60d5806ae4b0b6b5a164633a'
headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36"}

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting a `403 Forbidden` error, which you can see using `requests.head`. Use [RJ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11380795/rj-adriaansen)'s suggestion to defeat huffpost's robot blocking.

```
>>> requests.head(url)
<Response [403]>
```